# Cell in many different ViewControllers

Tags: swift, alert, uiactivityviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I have a cell which I use in many different vc because I have my app divided in different categories but all use the same cell.

Now I have a button which should trigger the event to share it via other apps like whastapp or facebook.
The problem is that depending on in which category you are you have a different view controller which will display the function.
I can make it work with one but not with 10 different vc in just one cell.

I used an extension to get the parentviewController

```
extension UIView {
var parentViewController: HomeViewController? {
    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
        if parentResponder is UIViewController {
            return parentResponder as! HomeViewController!
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

This will obviously only work at the Home vc.

How can I work around this issue?

Comment: You should control your UIViews from your UIViewController, not the other way around. This is a very bad hack and you really shouldn't use it.

Comment: Please tell me how

Comment: I would have to understand your archiecture to be able to help, sorry

Comment: can I assign it at the cellForRow?  cell.parentVc = HomeviewController().  ?

Comment: your cell should have a single responsibility, which is showing its information on screen. It should not know about its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use a protocol to handle your button action in the view controller:**

```
protocol ShareEventDelegate: class {
    func didShareButtonSelected()
}
```

**In your custom cell:**

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var shareDelegate: ShareEventDelegate?

    func yourButtonAction() { 
       shareDelegate.didShareButtonSelected?()
    }
}
```

**Then make your ViewControllers conform to the ShareEventDelegate, for example:**

```
extension HomeViewController: ShareEventDelegate {
    func didShareButtonSelected() {
        // handle your action here
    }
}
```

**And in cellForRow:**

```
cell.shareDelegate = self
```

Comment: first of all thanks, I made it work now via posting notification :)